# Multithreading and consistency models

Tags: multithreading, x86

Here, in this example, I'm assuming that we're on a X86 system with at least two physical cores and thread #1 and #2 is running on it's own CPU core (true parallelism):

```
[initial state]
shared_memory_location = 0;

[thread #1]
shared_memory_location = 1;
signal();

[thread #2]
wait_for_signal();
print(shared_memory_location);
```

What's the value of `shared_memory_location` on thread #2?

This is my take on this: It could have been either `0` or `1` but the consistency model of X86 ensures that any read after a memory location write will read the new value regardless of which CPU core this read is occurring on.

The X86 consistency model will ensure that the second physical core executing thread #2 doesn't pick up an invalid value from the CPU core private cache. X86 makes this a lot easier but there's no guarantees that any other system such as ARM will behave in this way.

If you didn't have the consistency model of X86 how would you ensure that thread #2 was able to read the new value when it is signaled from thread #1?

...or more to the point, how do you hand of a value to a thread which is waiting on a signal in a correct manner?

**DISCLAIMER: I could be completely wrong about the X86 consistency model, please correct me if I am!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `signal()` and `wait_for_signal()` methods calls memory barrier internally, then the scenario you describe will not occurs even on ARM, because of the memory barrier call flushes the data to the main memory instead of private core cache, i.e at the `signal` method it will flushes the data to main memory, so the `shared_memory_location` will be "volatile write", and it will also flushes the data to to the main memory after the `wait_for_signal`, so reading `shared_memory_location` will be "volatile read".

Comment: I've heard about memory barriers before but how do you use them? What is it that you barricade? is this just a compiler trick?

Comment: memory barrier or memory fence generally used to forbid the cpu from reordering the instructions, it exposed into two parts: half fence and a full fence.. it is really a large topic to describe here, but you can find more specific details on memory barrier [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686355(v=vs.85).aspx) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier)

Comment: There is no modern CPU that I know of that 'flushes' to main memory. That would be extremely inefficient.